# HHTML5 Video Scrolling - Video Encoding Issues

Tags: javascript, html, video, encoding, scroll

There's an amazing way to use your mouse scroll to control the frames of a html5 video, very neat.

Original: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mJwbK

```
<video id="v0" tabindex="0" autobuffer="autobuffer" preload="preload"><source type="video/mp4; codecs=&quot;avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2&quot;" src="http://dehsigner.com.br/download/animacao_2mb.mp4"></source>
```

Sorry, your browser does not support the <video> element.

My problem is, when applying to my video, the execution is very "buggy/choppy" on Chrome and Firefox, i've tried a lot of different encoding options, but so far, no success, see the code-pen:

My video: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LGzRVN

Anyone knows how to fix this? Encoding options maybe?

Cheers!

Comment: my guess is that it's going to relate to the length of the video - their sample seems much longer than yours so the math that's positioning things can be more granular as it has more frames to work from

Comment: That was my first guess, but changing that number didn't fix the rendering issue.

Comment: Important to mention: It renders perfectly in Safari.

Comment: I have same exact issue. All videos render smoothly in Safari but in Chrome/Firefox they are choppy. From my research, it is related to the encoding of the video. NYTimes has a great interactive video bound to scroll that renders smoothly in all browsers. Using this video (mp4), I have no issue.

https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2019/07/31/us/assault-weapons-ban.html

I've tried other examples but cannot figure out what is required to successful encode the video to work correctly in Chrome and Firefox.